# Windows DNS dnscmd.exe SecureList syntax

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

DnsCmd let's you provide a list of nameservers to allow for secure zone transfers, however providing a list like `127.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.4` causes the machine to consume memory and CPU until it crashes (give it a shot).

Full syntax:

```
dnscmd servername /ZoneResetSecondaries zonename /SecureList '127.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.4' /Notify
```

What is the correct way to provide a list of nameservers to dnscmd.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, figured this one out quickly.  Omit the single quotes around the list of IP addresses.

i.e.

```
dnscmd servername /ZoneResetSecondaries zonename /SecureList 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.4 /Notify
```